# CMakeLists is not generating so file

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

Following is my CMakeLists.txt file

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
>
> add_library(
>                native-lib
>                SHARED
>                src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
>
> find_library(
>                 log-lib
>                 log )
>
> target_link_libraries(
>                          native-lib
>                          ${log-lib} )

I have specified, `SHARED` in `add_library` since I want a shared object library.

But it is not giving me the so file.

what am I missing?

Comment: After you've created CMakeLists.txt, what do you do?

Comment: i just cd into the directory containing my cpp files and i run `make`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that CMake doesn't compile anything ? It just configures a Makefile (or IDE project's files) for you.

Generate your Makefile / Visual Studio / What ever you use file project via CMake and then compile.

You will have your library then ;)

Comment: can u please explain `Generate your Makefile / Visual Studio / What ever you use file project via CMake and then compile.`

Comment: CMake is a software which configures project's files, it does not compile you anything.

If you use cmake-gui, you have tu press the button "Generate" after openning your CMakeFiles.txt. Then, in your  destination folder, you will have the project file you have selected in the menu just after "Generate" (Unix Makefiles for example)